# Android: Cargaste un APK con una firma que no es válida

Tags: android

Estoy tratando de subir por primera vez una aplicación a la play store pero me está votando el siguiente error:

> Cargaste un APK con una firma que no es válida (obtén más información sobre las firmas). Error de apksigner: ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_SIGNATURES: No JAR signatures

Ya generé varias firmas pero sigue saliendo el mismo error hasta seleccioné las opciones que aparecen con checkbox (V1 y V2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la solución, Simplemente borrar la carpeta:

> build

Antes de eliminar la carpeta, cierren android studio, una vez que eliminan la carpeta abren el proyecto y van a "Build -> Clean Project", luego firman el apk y ya podrán subirlo a la play store.

Espero que le sirva a alguien.

Comment: en 24 horas marca la respuesta como aceptada, ayudarás a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas) gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que simplemente te confundiste de .apk ya que el que se genera en el directorio `/debug` no se usa para subir a Google Play

El .APK que debes usar para Google Play es el contenido en el directorio `/release`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si usas .APK contenido en el directorio `/debug` que se firma con el keystore de depuración, se mostrará el mensaje:

> Cargaste un APK con una firma que no es válida (obtén más información
>   sobre las firmas). Error de apksigner: ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_SIGNATURES:
>   No JAR signatures

---

Si realizas un `Build` -> `Clean Project` esto no realiza modificación en los .APK ya que estos se encuentra de hecho en otros directorios (`/release`, `/debug`) en el mismo nivel.

Comment: Hola, lo que subí a la play store fue el apk contenida en la carpeta release. había intentado crear una nueva firma pero seguía sin solucionar el problema. La solución fue borrar la carpeta "Build" del proyecto, lo de "Clean Project" es para asegurarme que no queden archivos basura en el proyecto.